# Pushing keys and properties from object to array

Tags: javascript

I would like to push all properties and keys from objects, including nested ones. That's how i'm trying:

```js
'use strict';

var getProps = function getProps(destination, object) {
 destination = destination || [];
 for (var key in object) {
   typeof object[key] === 'object' && object[key] !== 'null'
? destination.push(getProps(destination, object[key]))
: destination.push(key);
 }
 return destination;
}

var object = {
 one: {
  two: 'three'
 }
};


console.log(getProps([], object))
```

As you can see, isn't working properly.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE -

Desire output:

```
['one', 'two', 'three'];
```

Comment: You haven't defined what you expect as output. "Not working properly" does not help if "properly" is not defined. I can see that it simply returns the input *destination* value without assigning any properties or values to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use recursion to achieve your desired result.

```js
var object = {
 one: {
  two: 'three'
 },
  
        four: {
            five: 'six',
            seven: [
              'eight',
              'nine',
              'ten'
            ],
            eleven: {
              twelve: {
                thirteen: {
                   fourteen: 'fifteen'
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

function rabbitHole(output, object) {
   for (var i in object) {
     if (!Array.isArray(object)) {
         output.push(i);
     }
 
     if (typeof object[i] == 'object') {
         rabbitHole(output, object[i]);
     } else {
         output.push(object[i]);
     }
   }
   return output;
}

var output = rabbitHole([], object);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: `typeof` will never return `array`. for an array, it will return `"object"`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I edited my response.  Your answer is pretty slick.  Stringify was my initial thought but I couldn't get it figured out quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use side-effects of `JSON.stringify` to simplify your code.

```
function keysAndVals(object) {
  var result = [];
  JSON.stringify(object, function(key, val) {
    result.push(key);
    if (typeof val !== "object") result.push(val);
    return val;
  });
  return result;
}
```